# Application stop working on eap 6.4 but enable/disable datasource, reload then works

Tags: jboss, jboss-eap-6, okd

I have application's which has deployed on Jboss eap 6.4 container. Application make connection with postgres. I am observing my web application stop working( can't fetch data from db). but if enable/disable data source then reload from jboss cli. Its working for some time. Please suggest on same.

try to pool min/pool max size, background validation true.

There are no error show in container logs

Comment: What errors are you getting in the server.log?It could be due to connection leak,or connection pool exhaustion due to high user load/connections in use,start by closing the connection objects being used in your application code once there usage is complete for starters.You could then also try tuning your connection pool as per users

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have a connection leak. Take a look at the logs; that should give you more information, also look at the number of active connections.
Your app works after the enable/disable because that will terminate all the connections to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Besides what Gerardo A. mentioned, since you changed EAP version is worth verifying the PostGres driver as well and configuration, below is an example of configuration:

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.postgresql">
  <resources>
  <resource-root path="postgresql-9.1-902.jdbc4.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <dependencies>
  <module name="javax.api"/>
  <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
  </dependencies>
</module>
```

Comment: Hi Sweta, it's me Francisco, it's been awhile. Well, not sure who you're replying haha!